# WPF radiobuttons IsHitTestVisible not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm using radiobuttons inside a listbox and cannot disable them.
After searching I found links about IsEnabled and IsHitTestVisible. When I set IsEnabled to false the button and text turns grey however it's still clickable. Setting IsHitTestVisible does nothing to change this. My XAMLcode looks like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source}" BorderThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSource, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <RadioButton IsHitTestVisible="{Binding IsEnabled}"  IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}" Margin="0 2 0 0" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Segoe UI Regular" Content="{Binding name}" GroupName="GroupList"  >
                <RadioButton.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" />
                    </Style>
                </RadioButton.Style>
            </RadioButton>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Property in c# that calculates and returns bool.

```
public bool IsEnabled
{     
    get
    {
        IsEnabledCalculate();
        return isEnabled;
    }
}
```

Any ideas about how to disable selection?

Comment: Where is you INotifyPropertyChange implementation? this property will never notify the UI that there is a change without it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `IsHitTestVisible` on a `RadioButton` in `ListBox` was a good start. This way, when you click the `RadioButton`, the event goes "through" it and is handled by `ListBoxItem` (the item gets selected). You can then manipulate `IsChecked` property by binding it do `IsSelected` property of the `ListBoxItem`.

This is however still not enough to achieve waht you want. First, you're binding your `IsEnabled` property on the wrong level: the `RadioButton`. As you noticed, this still allows the `ListBoxItem` to get selected. So, you need to bind your `IsEnabled` property to the `IsEnabled` property of `ListBoxItm` instead:

```
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled"  Value="{Binding Path=IsEnabled}"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

There still is one minor issue here. When your `IsEnabled` property is changed in the codebehind, the `ListBoxItem` will get disabled but the `RadioButton` will still be checked. To prevent this and uncheck the `RadioButton` whenever the item gets disabled you can use a `DataTrigger`:

```
           <DataTemplate>
                <RadioButton GroupName="GroupList" IsHitTestVisible="False"
                     Margin="0 2 0 0" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Segoe UI Regular" 
                     Content="{Binding name}" >
                    <RadioButton.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled}" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </RadioButton.Style>
                </RadioButton>
            </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you, that works! Now I just have the issue of not being able to update the values on propertychanged but one thing at a time

Comment: @SEASN which property do you mean?